# When writing a scientific report, is it better to define every letter each time an equation is introduced or only for the new letters?

Tags: scientific-publishing

Of the two examples, which is better:

(A)

```
 a = b + c,                          (1)
 where a is ..., b is ..., and c is ...

 [some paragraphs]

 d = a / e                           (2)
 where d is ..., a is ..., and e is ...
```

(B)

```
 a = b + c,                          (1)
 where a is ..., b is ..., and c is ...

 [some paragraphs]

 d = a / e                           (2)
 where d is ..., and e is ...
```

Comment: I mean, I personally feel as long as the values of the variables didn’t change, you can only call them once. But if the values change, it’s best to readdress them.

Comment: Do you have just (1) and (2), or (3), (4)... as well, so the reader has to go back through a number of them to see where the variable was defined?

Answer (score 1):

What @expert said plus:

If the equations are independent of each other, explain all variables for each equation. If the equations are steps in a process (e.g. a proof), define all variables once. If you explain each of the steps, define the variables as they are mentioned in the explanation.